# IBM DS3512 Connection to IBM HS22 BladeCenter

Tags: ibm, hardware, bladecenter, blade-server

I have a BladeCenter HS22 with 14 bladeservers. Attached to the BladeCenter I have a DS3512 storage array. I'm trying to access the DS3512 to configure it but can't manage to do it.

I have connected to the two SAS modules IPs via the IBM Storage Configuration Manager but this doesn't give me the option to setup the drives in the DS3512, it only allows me to configure the zones for the blade servers. Do I need to first connect to the management port of the DS3512 and set it up that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this and has the same question:

You must configure two of the four management ports, one from each controller. I used the left port and the default IP's for these was 192.168.128.101 and 102. You then need to use the latest version of IBM System Storage DS Storage Manager and connect to both IP's.

Answer (score 0):

You need DS Storage Manager software in order to config the DS3512. You can download it from IBM website

Comment: Can you link to the software he needs?

Comment: I believe this is the software: http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5079595

Comment: I understand I need to use this software to connect to the DS3512. I can connect to the SAS modules. My question is do I need to configure the IP addresses of the management ports and connect to them using this software?